# Assigning values to a string pointer

Tags: c++, string

I am currently analysing the char and string datatypes. For `char` data types, the following code snipped holds good:

```
char value = 'a';
char value1[] = "Good";
char* value2 = "Good";
```

For strings,

```
string strValue = "Good";
string strVal[3] = {"Good","Better","Best"};
```

But the assignment below throws the compilation error:

> "error: scalar object strPtr requires one element in initializer"

```
string* strPtr = {"Good","Better","Best"}
```

So, how to assign values to above `string*` initially?

Thanks,
Udhai

Comment: `char* value2 = "No good";` -- Through an error in language design, it is allowed, but it shouldn't be, and it is deprecated.  String literals reside in read only memory, and in that statement, you are assigning a non-const pointer to the first element of one.  So if you try to modify the string, it will compile, but it will not work at runtime.  That's bad.

Comment: Pointers point to an address; right? Therefore, when you "assign" a value to a pointer, you must first de-reference it, which then allows you to actually work with the data at the address the pointer points to. Trying to assign a value to a non-de-referenced pointer is saying that you're trying to change the address of the data you're pointing to. What you assign to a `string *` is an already defined, or at least declared, `string`.

Comment: Hasn't that been fixed in the meantime? I thought nowadays (C++ 0x or maybe a later version of the standard) string literals always have the type const char* (and this should yield a compilation error).

Comment: For the record, the GCC flag `-Wwrite-strings` helps debugging the issue pointed out by Benjamin.

Comment: What's the use case for `string* strPtr = {"Good","Better","Best"}`? If your declare as `string[]`, you can assign to `string*`, so there should normally be no need to do this. Since initialising this way places the array on the stack (thus you must not call `delete[]` on the pointer), and reassigning the pointer later to something usally allocated on the heap is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Pointers are not arrays, so why would you want to pretend otherwise? You could do this however

```
string strVal[3] = {"Good","Better","Best"};
string* strPtr = strVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
std::string* strPtr{new std::string[3]{"Good","Better","Best"}};
```

This also compiles

```
std::string* strPtr{(std::string[3]){"Good","Better","Best"}};
```

but binds the pointer to a temporary, so please don't do that.

Comment: In the first example, you create the array on the heap, not stack, and have to delete manually if you don't want your memory to leak.

Comment: @Axel: That depends on the lifetime...  If it's a global, there's no need to ever deallocate it, since globals should live until the end of the program.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you refer to `std::string`.

The correct way is

```
std::string *s(new std::string);
// or
std::string *s = new std::string;
```

if you want a pointer to a string and

```
std::string s_arr[3] = {"Good","Better","Best"};
string* str_p = s_arr;
```

if you want a pointer pointing to the start of an array of strings.

Comment: `...(new std::string;` are you missing a )?